# How to grant permissions, in Windows 10, to a folder in a server to a user connected to a workgroup?

Tags: windows, networking, workgroup

I, as a network admistrator, want to grant permission to read and edit a folder and all its files to a user (another computer in the workgroup).

I tried the following: properties of said folder, security, edit, add new permission, advance settings, find now, accept, accept, ganat all permissions of verified users and accept one last time. However, to the user, the monitor shows a message saying he doesn´t have permisson to acces the object and should contact the network administrator.

Comment: Workgroup? I hope you mean AD group…

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows File Permissions and Attributes](https://serverfault.com/questions/516989/windows-file-permissions-and-attributes)

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot do that. But you can create the same username on both hosts, with the same password. Windows will be default attempt to connect with the current username and password.

Then assign permissions to the local account on the host that has the share/resource.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a local user on the server where the data is located and then assign the permissions. You can also do that using PowerShell. But it's not best practice, ideally the data should be located on a file server and the user access the data with an active directory account.
If the user is in a workgroup he is not connection to the domain. A workaround for that, that the user uses a step stone server or a virtual desktop which is connected to the domain. It's totally unmanageable if an user is in a workgroup and should be avoided also for security reasons.

Here is an example

```
# Define user information
$Username = "NewUser"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "Password123" -AsPlainText -Force
$FullName = "New User Full Name"

# Create a new local user
New-LocalUser -Name $Username -Password $Password -FullName $FullName

# Define folder and permissions
$FolderPath = "C:\Path\To\Your\Folder"
$Permission = "FullControl"
$Acl = Get-Acl -Path $FolderPath

# Add permissions to the folder for the new user
$Rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($Username, $Permission, "Allow")
$Acl.SetAccessRule($Rule)
Set-Acl -Path $FolderPath -AclObject $Acl
Set-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup "File And Printer Sharing" -Enabled True -Profile Any​
```

Save this as for example access.ps1 and run this with administrator privileges (elevated). Change the variables to the values you desire